# backing up sharepoint 2007 lists

Tags: 2007, list, development

I want to backup my SharePoint 2007 Lists. Now I am not sure, if there is any possibility of doing it in C# code or If I will have to perform few actions like following some steps and make it do using GUI.

I looked at Google and find out that I can export it to excel or Access but how can I do it pro grammatically + it will be synchronized as well.

I find this Script as well that tells how to export a list to excel using C# but how it will keep sychronized, most likely I will have to use it once to get all the items and then create a event receiver that will repeat this step for the added item,

[Export to excel c#](http://www.etechplanet.com/blog/export-sharepoint-list-to-excel-spreadsheet-programmatically-using-c.aspx)

Not sure if it gonna be the best practice tho, or any alternative.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question I am making this assumption that you are only looking to backup lists along with content and not the entire site. Additionally you want all your lists within a site or subsite to be backed up at one go.

Please refer to a similar discussion over here that address your problem :- [What's the best way to move a list from one site to another?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/718/whats-the-best-way-to-move-a-list-from-one-site-to-another)

Comment: thanks for your answer but I dont think if that answer was any helpful to me, however I added my answer to his problem :)

Cheers

Comment: We didn't required to backup lists I miss understood requirements, so I accepted yur answer right